# mult vs broadcast in core.async

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

Im playing around with core.async and find it very fun to work with. However I fail at understanding what are the different use cases for mult and broadcast. Are they both needed or will one be replaced by the other?
So far the only difference i have found is that it is easier to tap in and untag with mult. Not sure how to unsubscribe from a broadcast, is this the only difference?

Below I have an example showing how to solve a problem using both methods.

```
;; Using mult with tap
(def in (chan))
(def multiple (mult in))

(def out-1 (chan))
(tap multiple out-1)

(def out-2 (chan))
(tap multiple out-2)

(go (>! in "PutIN"))

(go (prn "From out-1: " (<! out-1)))
(go (prn "From out-2: " (<! out-2)))
```

//

```
;; Using broadcast
(def bout-1 (chan))
(def bout-2 (chan))
(def broadcast-in (broadcast bout-1 bout-2))

(go (>! broadcast-in "PutINBroadcast"))
(go (prn "From bout-1: " (<! bout-1)))
(go (prn "From bout-2: " (<! bout-2)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the note to the `clojure.core.async.lab` namespace with `broadcast`.

> core.async HIGHLY EXPERIMENTAL feature exploration
>
> Caveats:
>
> 1. Everything defined in this namespace is experimental, and subject to change or deletion without warning.
> 2. Many features provided by this namespace are highly coupled to implementation details of core.async. Potential features which operate
>      at higher levels of abstraction are suitable for inclusion in the
>      examples.
> 3. Features provided by this namespace MAY be promoted to clojure.core.async at a later point in time, but there is no guarantee
>      any of them will.

Nobody has worked on it for a long time now, it has never been ported to ClojureScript. I'd expect it to be removed from core.async in the near future. `mult` is the later development.